# Periodic wifi network interuption : Realtek RTL8723be wifi adapter

Tags: wireless, 16.04, internet

This problem has occured to me many times before. I connect to my home wifi network and then i can browse pages and download stuff. But after sometime suddenly pages stop loading and downloads get interuppted. I updated to 16.04 lts but problem still persists. I searched this site for answers but it seems that this problem can occur due to multiple reasons and hence I cannot determine mine. Since i am a total newbie in using ubuntu I do not know how to exaclty present my problem. Any help in cornering up the problem and finding the solution would be a great help.

One more thing. The temporary thing which i can do now is to disconnect the wifi and then connect again. But the problem returns back within 10-15 min.

Comment: Please give details about the wifi-adapter in your computer ?

Comment: You can also post the output  when you run this in the terminal.   `lspci |grep Network`   . Terminal can be opened by Ctrl+Alt+T

Comment: 08:00.0 Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter

Comment: I tried anothor driver as the post said by disabling secure boot and the problem is gone

Comment: Same thing happens to me on a Qualcomm Atheros AR9485 wifi adapter. Frequent interupptions for no apparent reason at all. When i  try to reconnect the wifi connection offers 4 different options for the SAME network: network_same_name_1, network_same_name_2, network_same_name_3, network_same_name_4. It makes no difference which one i choose. They all connect well... just to auto disconnect a while later.